# Incorect Daemon Configuration

Tags: android, daemon

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

I have tried all solutions but not a single solution works for me...

What is the really problem here

Comment: Which solutions did you try? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: What was the full log or the process output? Also, maybe your firewall/antivirus is blocking gradle?